# Google sign in stopped working on play store build

Tags: android, google-play-console, playback

Google sign in was working previously and Users were using it. Recently I have updated my sign in Key in play console. The sign in works in debug, Also when we create release apk it works. Bugt when we deploy it on play store It stops working. Though it works for few devices. I checked the sha 1 keys and all the keys that were there in play console are available in firebase console as well as gcm credentials. I am unable to figure out what might be the reason.

Comment: Might be related to SHA fingerprint . Create Signed build with debuggable optipn enable and check the error code or exception u r getting

Comment: I matched the sha fingerprint. It is same. The weird thing is that It is working for some gmail Id's. WHile It is not working for few Id's.